# Rails Way: Take a link on show page of one controller and connect it to new page of another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have on my holder (think of it as a relationships table holding all the questions that belong to a certain holder and the holder specific data like name) show page a list of questions and a link to New Question link.

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= question.question %> 
    <%= question.answer %>
    <%= link_to "Edit Question", edit_question_path(question) %>
    <br />
<% end %>

<%= link_to "New Question", new_question_path %>
```

The goal of this is to set the holder_id when the new question is created. I have the belongs_to and has_many setup in the model if that matters.

I've tried a few different things such as `<%= link_to "New Question", new_question_path(@holder) %>` but that just sets the format: to the @holder.id. I suppose, I could abuse that to make it work, but that's a very ugly hack.

I've heard people over use nested routes, and not to go more than 2 or 3 deep. So there's got to be a way to do this without using nested routes.

1. Am I correct in that there is a way to do this without using nested routes? What is it?
2. Why would nested routes be a good or bad idea for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can do something like this.
In your link to new:

```
<%= link_to "New Question", new_question_path(:holder_id => @holder.id)
```

This link will make your request send **holder_id** as a parameter to the **new** action in your **question_controller.rb**. So you can use it like this:

```
def new
  holder_id = params[:holder_id]
  # Do something with this id
  # ...
end
```

Comment: But, you would typically use nested routes then?

Comment: Depends. If a holder model would be always nested inside questions, with no views/controllers standalone, then i would definitely use nested routes.